# Creating template function overloads for pointer and non pointer type data held inside a container

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a template function that is overloaded for pointer and non pointers. I did this and it works.

```
    template<class D, class V>
    bool Same(D d, V v){ return d == v; }

    template<class D, class V>
    bool Same(D* d, V v) { return *d==v;}
```

Now I want to extend it such that a templated container is a paramater and there must be one version for the container with pointer  and other with the container for non pointers. I am not able to figure it out. I tried this but it won't work.

```
    template< template<class> class Container, class Data, class Value>
    bool func(Container<Data> &c, Value v)
    {
        return c[0] == v;
    }

    template< template<class> class Container, class Data, class Value>
    bool func(Container<Data*> &c, Value v)
    {
            return *c[0] == v;
    }
```

The error c2040 says int* differs in level of indirection from int and points to the first function.

How can I get it to work?

Rest of thecode

```
template<class D>
class Vec
{
    std::vector<D> m_vec;
public:
    void push_back(D d) { m_vec.push_back(d); }
        D operator[](int i) { return m_vec[i]; }
};
void test_template()
{
    Same<int, int>(2,3);
    Info i = {4};
    Same<Info, int>(i, 2);
    Info ii = {2 };
    Info *pi = &ii;
    Same<Info, int>(pi, 2);

    Vec<int> iv;
    iv.push_back(3);
    func<Vec, int, int>(iv, 3);
    Vec<int*> pv;
    pv.push_back(new int(3));
    func<Vec, int*, int>(pv, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second call to `func`, the second template parameter should just be `int`, not `int *`. Otherwise, the second `func` declaratino will look for a `Vec<int **>` as the first template argument (since it has its own pointer).

```
func<Vec, int, int>(pv, 3);
```

**EDIT:** as DyP mentioned, you can also leave out the template arguments completely, as the compiler should be able to deduce them from the actual function arguments.